# List all the taxonomy terms in a particular vocabulary in Drupal 6.

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

My task is to display all the terms in a particular vocabulary. It should also display all the sub-terms along with their parent terms.

For example the taxonomy page for a particular vocabulary is like

Term 1

Term 2

Term 3

```
Sub-term 1 of Term 3

Sub-term 2 of Term 3

Sub-term 3 of Term 3
```

Term 4

Term 5

Term 6

Sub term 1 of Term 6

Sub term 2 of Term 6

I need an exact display of taxonomy terms as above (without edit, just to list all the terms in a tree order). Is it possible with views or whether I have to do coding? I tried this thing with views by giving term- weight filter, taxonomy parent term relationships etc, received duplicate values and found it very complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`taxonomy_get_tree()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6)

**Parameters**

**$vid:** Which vocabulary to generate the tree for.

**$parent:** The term ID under which to generate the tree. If 0, generate the tree for the entire vocabulary.

**$depth:** Internal use only. Now deprecated and isn't used. It is left here only because of compatibility issues.

**$max_depth:** The number of levels of the tree to return. Leave NULL to return all levels.

API [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6)

Comment: Thank you very much. I made it with taxonomy_get_tree().

Comment: @Anson consider choosing the correct answer.